# Is this way the best way to create this type of navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Okay so my navigation is positioned absolute. Also I have a div above that also positioned absolute but with a z index of 2. When you click a toggle button the div with the z-index of 2 gets 240 pixels of margin added to the left revealing the navigation below it. This works perfectly apart from on mobile you can see the navigation below the div by scrolling. How can I fix this?

My website is up at http://www.zoidstudios.com/

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/ZoidCraft/pen/KrRvjr

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Examples</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<header class="top-header">
    <button class="menu-toggle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </button>
    <h1>Zoid Studios</h1>
    <h2>A <span>visual design</span> studio based in the <span>united kingdom</span></h2>
    <a class="btn-view" href="">view our work <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</header>



.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #080911;
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
  .main-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; }
  .main-nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
    .main-nav a:hover {
      color: #ffff00; }

.shift {
  margin-left: 240px; }

.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .menu-toggle span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 18px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 4px; }

.top-header {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #101223;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
  .top-header h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 25px 0;
    text-align: center; }
  .top-header h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize; }
    .top-header h2 span {
      color: #ffff00; }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .top-header h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 0 10px 30px 10px; }
  .top-header h2 {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    margin: 0 10px 30px 10px; } }
.btn-view {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ffff00;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }
  .btn-view i {
    padding-left: 10px; }
  .btn-view:hover {
    color: #101223;
    background-color: #ffff00;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); }
```

Is there another way of doing this exact way of side navigation?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: do not use width:100%, but coordonates ....

Comment: what do you mean exactly? @GCyrillus

Comment: remove width and use right and left to 0 for the header ...

Comment: Doesnt resolve the issue :( @GCyrillus

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjxrwV sure ? but 240px for a mobile menu is not it too big or too little ? better have header drop underneath a this point